# Without my suffix, you've lost the game

Tags: riddle, word

> My prefix has very little
> My infix is used to mark
> Without my suffix, you've lost the game
> My whole is what you are doing right now.

Comment: Hate to be that guy but rot13 Lbh pna'g or jvgubhg xvat va purff, n cbfvgvba jvgubhg obgu xvatf ba gur obneq vf abg n yrtny cbfvgvba.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am thinking it might be

> thinking

Prefix has very little

> thin

Infix is used to mark

> ink

Without suffix, you've lost the game

> King in chess

My whole is what you are doing right now

> :)

Comment: Just beat me to it, about 10 seconds in between there :P Also welcome back! Long time no see :)

Answer (score 7):

The answer is

> '**THINKING**'!

---

My prefix has very little

> '**THIN**' meaning having very little

My infix is used to mark

> '**INK**' in pens is used to mark

Without my suffix, you've lost the game

> In chess, you lose the game if you lose your '**KING**'

My whole is what you are doing right now.

> '**THINKING**' to solve the puzzle!

Comment: It's really unfortunate that you got beaten by 46 seconds lol. I'll give an upvote though.

Comment: @Ankit I didn't actually realise Id been beaten until the page refreshed :P Thank you, although LR deserves the credit for getting it first!

Comment: lol np, at first I thought u copied Lukas but when i checked the history i realized theres no way to rewrite all of that in 46 seconds lol.